# How to call a python script to process hundreds of text files parallely using make?

Tags: python-2.7, makefile

I have hundreds of text files in a folder named "in/". I need to run a python script which takes one file at a time, process it and drop it in a folder named "out/". I have the python script in place to do this.
As the number of text files to be processed are very large (10000) and as all the file processing are independent I wanted to use "make -j" to get the best out of my CPU which has 8 cores. I created a make file which looks like this :

```
SCRIPT_DIR:=/home/xyz/abc/scriptFolder<br/>
IN_DIR:=/home/xyz/abc/data/in/in10000<br/>
OUT_DIR:=/home/xyz/abc/data/out/out10000<br/><br/>
chk:  
    cd $(OUT_DIR); \<br/>
    python $(SCRIPT_DIR)/process_parallel.py --inFile $(IN_DIR)/\*
```

As mentioned process_parallel.py takes in one file at a time processes it and drops it as a text file in the current folder which is OUT_DIR. I ran htops after this and checked. I could see only one process running, where as I should have seen 8 as I ran it with -j 8. Can you please guide me where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is writing a shell script to do this. Something like:

```
for f in in/*.txt;
do
    ./process_parallel.py $f &
done
wait
```

Your OS scheduler should take care of parallelizing the processing across the CPU cores.  You can then call the script inside your Makefile.

There's also GNU Parallel https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: With make -j option we can force creation of many threads of execution and execute the independent processes on separate cores. So I am looking for make specific solution.